# Android Studio, only one value gets saved to my Firebase Database despite the handler

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello so I have checkboxes here:

```
        First = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch1);

        Second = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch2);

        Third = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch3);

        ch4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch4);

        ch5 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch5);

        ch6 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch6);

        ch7 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch7);

        ch8 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch8);

        ch9 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch9);

        ch10 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch10);

        ch11 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch11);
to the 100th...
```

And I have its handler here:

```
    public void setParameter(CheckBox param){

        Intent inte = getIntent();
        String RoomName = inte.getStringExtra("RoomName");


        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
        DatabaseReference reference = mFirebaseDatabase1.child(RoomName).child(date).child("Inspection").child(currentDateTimeString);

        if(param.isChecked())
        {
            String trek = param.getText().toString();
            reference.child(trek).setValue("Yes");
return;


        }
        else
        {
            String trek = param.getText().toString();
            reference.child(trek).setValue("No");
            return;

        }

    }
```

And I apply it by doing this at some part of my code:

```
   setParameter(First);
                setParameter(Second);
                setParameter(Third);
                setParameter(ch4);
                setParameter(ch5);
                setParameter(ch6);
                setParameter(ch7);
                setParameter(ch8);
                setParameter(ch9);
                setParameter(ch10);
                setParameter(ch11);
                setParameter(ch12);
                setParameter(ch13);
                setParameter(ch14);
                setParameter(ch15);
                setParameter(ch16);
                setParameter(ch17);
                setParameter(ch18);
                setParameter(ch19);
                setParameter(ch20);
                setParameter(ch21);
                setParameter(ch22);
                setParameter(ch23);
                setParameter(ch24);
                setParameter(ch25);
                setParameter(ch26);
                setParameter(ch27);
                setParameter(ch28);
                setParameter(ch29);
                setParameter(ch30);
                setParameter(ch31);
                setParameter(ch32);
                setParameter(ch33);
                setParameter(ch34);
                setParameter(ch35);
                setParameter(ch36);
                setParameter(ch37);
                setParameter(ch38);
                setParameter(ch39);
                setParameter(ch40);
                setParameter(ch41);
                setParameter(ch42);
                setParameter(ch43);
                setParameter(ch44);
                setParameter(ch45);
                setParameter(ch46);
                setParameter(ch47);
                setParameter(ch48);
                setParameter(ch49);
                setParameter(ch50);
                setParameter(ch51);

to the 100'th
```

My problem is in the database only one value gets saved. How is this happening? Here is my structure:

[image]

Any help is appreciated. I have been running in circles. I can't figure it out.
I have been doing this for hours now, I can't just get it right. It keeps giving one value, I tried CLEAN -> REBUILD and restarting the device nothing else works. I can't find out why this is happenign when i think I implemented the handler and implementation well. Please help

This is where `Entrance Louver` comes from:

```
First = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch1);
```

and I want to save all the other checkboxes

```
Second = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch2);

    Third = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch3);

    ch4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch4);
```

Define Checkboxes -> Make a handler -> pass it to handler -> Handler gets text in the texbox, converts it to string then saves it to firebase via

```
reference.child(trek).setValue("Yes");
```

if checked and if not

reference.child(trek).setValue("No");

trek is the converting text to string

Comment: Uggh, please use arrays! Also, `String RoomName = inte.getStringExtra("RoomName");` would appear to return the `RoomName` regardless of the `param` you pass in. I also don't think you are using intents properly. Finally, you should indicate what you hope your Firebase database should look like, and what it actually contains.

Comment: What do you mean you through "Only one value gets saved to my Firebase Database"? I see many dates there. Can be pelase more precise?

Comment: @AlexMamo the dates are her `currentDateTimeString` meaning she was supposed to save other than `Entrance Louver` I assume she has many values in her checkbox she wants to show not only the one i mentioned. That's how I understood her question.

Comment: @AnnYoon so you passed the checkbox boolean to the handler, and then it was supposed to get the text and convert it to a string and then become the child of the `currentDateTimeString ` and set it a value right?  Is this what you meant? Is this what you are trying?